# Select next enabled textbox if possible (jQuery, .Net 4)

Tags: jquery, select, blur

I have a .Net page with some textboxes, which are sometimes disabled.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="tb"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="tb" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" CssClass="tb"></asp:TextBox>
```

With jQuery, I want to do the following:

If a textbox loses the focus, I want to select the next enabled textbox if there are any.
Otherwise, I want to do something else (e.g. display a message).

I don´t know how to do that.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $('.tb').blur(function() {


    });

});
```

Generated html:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$TextBox1" class="tb" id="MainContent_TextBox1"  
  type="text"/>

<input name="ctl00$MainContent$TextBox2" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled tb"
  id="MainContent_TextBox2" type="text"/>

<input name="ctl00$MainContent$TextBox3" class="tb" id="MainContent_TextBox3" 
  type="text"/>
```

Comment: Are these inputs all siblings?  If so, are they all one after the other or are there other elements between them?

Comment: there is a lot to check there, you have to check what the current box is, you have to check if the current one isnt the last one etc I think I know a way how to do it but I doubt its the best possible way

Comment: @James No, there are no elements inbetween.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ()
 {
     $('.tb').blur(function ()
     {
         var t = $(this).nextAll(".tb:not([disabled])").eq(0);
         if(t.length == 0) alert('xxxx');
         else t.focus();
     });
 });
```

http://jsbin.com/ixevor/edit#javascript,html